# Issues using 'pdftotext' on Windows

Tags: pdf, pdftotext

I am trying to get text from a PDF file using the following command:

```
pdftotext.exe file.pdf file.txt
```

The problem is that if my PDF file contains any dashes (`-`) in the body, the resulted text file will not have them (using the `-layout` option will have same results).

**Example:**

- PDF file contains: `-5:00 Eastern Standard Time`
- Resulted TXT file will contain: `5:00 Eastern Standard Time`

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: If you try to copy&paste from Adobe reader, is the dash extracted then?

Comment: The text is encrypted so the copy/paste brings just gibberish characters. the PDFToText is able to correctly extract the text but any dashes are eliminated.

Comment: *copy/paste brings just gibberish* - that is a bad sign as Adobe acrobat and reader usually are quite good at text extraction. That been said, usually pdftotext does not drop dashes. Thus, the issue is specific for your PDF. If you want more details, please share the PDF.

Comment: You are correct. I have hundreds of PDFs which I was testing and the dashes got dropped for all of them. I did this test and downloaded from the Internet one PDF file which has dashes and PDFtoText did not drop it for that file. So, the issue was related to my files. Thanks mkl